# What are the names for localization

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

I have an app that I want to localize, and I would like to know the names for China, Taiwan, Hong Kong, Singapore for the values folder, such as values-TW(?), etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is defined in

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

The specific reference for 2 letter country codes are defined in
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements

China - CN
Hong Kong - HK
Taiwan - TW
Singapore - SG

Answer (score 0):

```
Taiwan    -> values-zh-rTW
Hong Kong -> values-zh-rHK
China     -> values-zh
Singapore -> values-zh-rSG
```